# Get data from SAP CRM to PHP

Tags: php, curl, netweaver, sap-crm

I'm trying to automate getting(posting) data from **[SAP CRM](https://cs.lenovo.com)** using my server (**cURL/PHP+MSSQL**), but have some problems with it.

There is no access allowed except this web interface.

I tried to use *cURL*, using *POST* fields from *FireBug*, but it returned only logon error.

Questions:

1. Is there any solution or API?
2. Has anybody tried it?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have access to SAP CRM at all? I suppose you are out of the luck with curl

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are APIs, though you'll have to be more specific about exactly what data you want in order to say if a particular API to serve your needs exists. SOAP web services are an option that may provide the information you need and there are PHP SOAP libraries. You'll need to talk to your SAP team to get access to the system, and you will probably want to be much more specific about the exact data you need access to.

If your company has Gateway, you can also define OData APIs. And it is, of course, possible to define your own RESTful (or other) HTTP APIs using SAP's HTTP stack. Again, you'll need to talk to your SAP team about this.

Comment: Company that using SAP does not provide any access except web interface :(

Comment: In that case, you'll need to have a discussion with that company explaining that if they want you to do this they will need to give you API access. Otherwise I'm afraid you're probably out of luck.